# How to check if id exists in another table with current user not fetch

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

My A table stored all update of my web and V table stored which update viewed by user.

Now I want to create a SELECT statement that not fetch table A's which
 id's date that id's of table V user_id=session id.

Case 1: To fetch all data from table A I used:

```
$id = 5, 10, 15; (for example)
$j = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM A WHERE `id`='".$id."' ORDER BY date DESC");
```

Case 2: Now select all ids where user_id = session id {If found any id reduce from case 1 fetch}

```
$myid = 50; ($session->id)
$p = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT post_id FROM V WHERE `post_id`='".$id."' AND `user_id` ='".$myid."'")
```

Table A:

```
id | from_id | to_id | date
---------------------------
5  |
10 |
15 |
20 |
```

Table V:

```
post_id | user_id 
-----------------
5       | 45
15      | 50 (see: this is my id)
```

From above example I want fetch only ids 5 , 10 data where 15 reduce for match user_id = session id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want as the English isn't perfect. ;)

However, I'm certain what you want is a JOIN. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html